# Why few date formats not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

When I apply the following code
new Date("25-06-2019") in javascript, it always gives invalid date. But the same format is working in PHP.

What can be the reason of this? not valid format for javascript?

Comment: Because Date objects in JS and PHP are nothing alike? [Check the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for why that is an invalid date. In short, it's neither ISO 8601 compliant, nor RFC 2822 compliant. You've essentially given `Date` a random collection of symbols.

Comment: To know more about date and time you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date/34015511#34015511

Comment: @Robin that's for formatting the content of a Date, not for constructing Dates.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use either an ISO 8601 date, or an RFC 2822 date. See (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

If you're doing something more sophisticated, I'd suggest using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), it will do a lot of Date parsing / formatting / manipulation for you.

For example:

```js
let iso8601Date = '2019-06-25';
console.log(new Date(iso8601Date));

let rfc2822Date = 'Tue, 25 Jun 2019 +0000'
console.log(new Date(rfc2822Date ));

// Or you can use moment.js which is great for date parsing, formatting, etc.
console.log(new moment.utc("25-06-2019", "DD-MM-YYYY"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`new Date("25-06-2019")` is giving you invalid date because you are passing invalid date string.

There are 4 ways to create a new date object:

```
new Date()
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
new Date(milliseconds)
new Date(date string)
```

So your case is 4th one, so valid date string will look like `October 13, 2014 11:13:00`
If you pass above date string say

```js
console.log(new Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00"));
```

It will work fine.

Also, you can provide valid ISO 8601 strings.

```js
console.log(new Date("2008-09-15"));
```

You can refer http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003169814.htm for ISO 8601 string formats.

Comment: (a subset of) ISO 8601 strings are also valid.

Comment: That link is not very useful - not every single ISO 8601 variation is supported - [the specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) define it in a more concise and more precise way.